# Mike works 5 days then takes 4 days off, will he be working in 220 days?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Mike is a security worker. He works 5 days and then takes 4 days off. If today is his third
day of the working schedule, determine will he be working after 220 days from today? Was he working 197 days ago?

I know the answer is:
No, he will be on his second day off; Yes. He will be on his fourth day of work;

But I don't know where to begin to get there. Could some one please help explain this to me?

Comment: What is $220 \pmod 9$? Call this number $k$. If $k \leq 5$, what do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use modular arithmetic. Since Mike's work schedule is $9$ days long, we can work (mod $9$). Today is the third day of the schedule, so *today* will be ($3$ mod $9$). So in $220$ days it will be the (($220+3$) mod $9$) day of Mike's work schedule. Similarly $197$ days ago was the (($3-197)$ mod $9$) day of his work schedule.

Answer (score 1):

The cycle repeats every $9$ days. Since $220=24\cdot 9+4$ we can consider the day $220$ as the day $4$ from today. Since today is the third day working he will work two more days and then $4$ days off. That is, he will not work after $4$ days from today and the same happens after $220$ days from today.

Answer (score 1):

If he is on the third day of working today, then he will be so again $9$ days from now. And again in $18$ days. And he will be on his third day of working in $90$ days, and in $180$ days. Can you do the rest from here?